Android Compose DropdownMenu with android:checkableBehavior="single" similar to xml menu
I am migrating my android xml layouts to compose and have hit an issue when trying to implement a drop down menu in compose that supports the following xml version of a dropdown menu
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="@string/my_title" android:enabled="false" />
    <group android:id="@+id/my_group" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/my_allocate"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_allocate"
            android:title="@string/context_menu_allocate" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/my_delete"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_delete"
            android:title="@string/context_menu_delete" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/my_context"
            android:icon="@drawable/my_context"
            android:title="@string/context_menu" />
    </group>
</menu>

is this possible in compose?
why doesnt androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenu &
androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem support dading groups

Could you share an image of what the result should look like?

see this question, which has GIF showing single selectable item in group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946231/independent-checkablebehavior-single-groups-in-navigationview-drawerlayout

also this example from google docs https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus#checkable

You can do something like this:
data class MenuItem(
    val name: String,
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val selectedIcon: ImageVector,
    val selected: Boolean = false
)

@Composable
fun Menu() {
    val menuItems = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(
            listOf(
                MenuItem(
                    name = "Home",
                    icon = Icons.Outlined.Home,
                    selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Home,
                    selected = false
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    name = "Favorites",
                    icon = Icons.Outlined.FavoriteBorder,
                    selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                    selected = false
                )
            ),
            listOf(
                MenuItem(
                    name = "Home",
                    icon = Icons.Outlined.Home,
                    selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Home,
                    selected = false
                ),
                MenuItem(
                    name = "Favorites",
                    icon = Icons.Outlined.FavoriteBorder,
                    selectedIcon = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                    selected = false
                )
            )
        )
    }

    val onClick = { groupId: Int, selectedItemIndex: Int ->
        val newGroup: MutableList<MenuItem> = mutableListOf()
        menuItems[groupId].forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            newGroup.add(item.copy(selected = index == selectedItemIndex))
        }
        menuItems[groupId] = newGroup
    }

    DropdownMenu(expanded = true, onDismissRequest = { }) {
        menuItems.forEachIndexed { groupIndex, group ->
            group.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = item.name) },
                    onClick = { onClick(groupIndex, index) },
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = if (item.selected) item.selectedIcon else item.icon,
                            contentDescription = item.name
                        )
                    },
                    trailingIcon = {
                        RadioButton(
                            selected = item.selected,
                            onClick = { onClick(groupIndex, index) }
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
            if (groupIndex < menuItems.size - 1) {
                HorizontalDivider()
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the result:

This code creates the menu view with the expected behavior. You can use the same logic to build a side menu or else.

nice work, i hadnt thought of using Compose RadioButton for the checkable affordance. gives me the idea of being able to support  single and multiple group checkable items using CheckBox as well
